# Deploying smart contract using geth

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using geth console to interact with the smart contract. I have followed the following link to deploy the smart contract. https://medium.com/@gus_tavo_guim/deploying-a-smart-contract-the-hard-way-8aae778d4f2a I am able to deploy the contract but "storage.get.call()" is always returning 0. The solidity version used in the link is 0.4.10. But I have used solidity version 0.5.11. And I have made changes in smart contract accordingly. Is the solidity version causing problem? What may be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the syntax of 0.5.11 is completely different to 0.4.10

I for my part still use 0.4.10 for my contracts (although I shouldn't).

I fixed the contract for you.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;
contract Storage {
  uint256 storedData;
  function set(uint256 data) public {
    storedData = data;
  }
  function get() public view returns (uint256) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

Use of `constant` is outdated now. Replace with `view`.

Furthermore, you need to set the `visibility` of the functions with `public`.

Deploy this new contract. Keep in mind to also get the new ABI. Then it should work.